# Cast char pointer to long

Tags: c

Firstly please forgive my limited c knowledge but how can I cast a char pointer into a long on both 32bit and 64bit platforms?  This code gives me a compiler warning C4311 with Visual Studio 2015

```
char *c;
long l;
l = (long)(c);
```

Thanks

Edit

Error code is **'type cast': pointer truncation from 'char *' to 'long'**
Can downvotes let me know why they have downvoted?

Comment: Why do you think it's reasonable **not** to include the warning message??!?

Comment: What is the warning message? There are many compiler warnings, how can we possibly know which one _you_ have encountered?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: perhaps you need `unsigned long long` instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4t91x2k5.aspx

Comment: @Amit and self I have edited by answer with compiler warning

Answer (score 6):

Don't do that if you can avoid it.

C99 (and newer) support a type named `uintptr_t`. It's an integral type that is capable of holding a pointer value. See [stddef.h](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) for more info.

Visual Studio is not known to fully support C99. Hence, you might not get that to work but it's worth a try.

```
char* c = <some value>;
uintptr_t ptr = (uintptr_t)c;
```

If you compile the c source file as C++ source, (using `/TC` compiler option), you should be able to use that.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of casting a pointer to an integer? You can use a union, or a struct, or possibly a void *.

Microsoft compilation environments default to LLP64, where a long is 32 bits wide, and that may be too narrow if your pointers are 64 bits wide. -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1.aspx

Comment: I believe routine is calculating a segment of memory as it is doing its own stack handling, so using intptr_t or uintptr_t is a solution?

Comment: simon-p-r, in that situation, there are the size_t and ptrdiff_t data types as well, but I contend that storing pointers into integers is abusive and causes code to be hard to read. My recommendations stand.

Comment: Ok I appreciate your comments