# Pointer truncation from 'BYTE *' to 'ULONG'

Tags: c++, drivers

I tried to write a simple filter driver for windows, When I want to build the project, Visual Studio gives me the following warning:

**Warning   C4311 'type cast': pointer truncation from 'BYTE *' to 'ULONG'**

and Error:
**C2220 warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated**

This is my code:

```
BOOLEAN GetAllBufferFromChunkedFormat(STREAM_EDIT_PARAMETERS* params, BYTE** 
dataBuffer)
{
if (!CheckPointer(params) || !CheckPointer(dataBuffer))
{
    return FALSE;
}
BYTE* iterator = params->dataStart + params->contentStart;
params->currentContentLength = 0;
UINT currentChunkLength = 0;
BOOLEAN isAllData = FALSE;
while ((ULONG)iterator - (ULONG)params->dataStart < params->streamEditor->dataLength) //calculate total length
{
    currentChunkLength = strtol(iterator, &iterator, 16);
    iterator += s_chunksSeparatorLength + currentChunkLength + s_chunksSeparatorLength;
    ..
    ..
    ..
}
```

The warning shows at line:

```
while ((ULONG)iterator - (ULONG)params->dataStart < params->streamEditor->dataLength)
```

What is the problem? and Why ?

Comment: `sizeof(BYTE *)` is not the same than `sizeof(ULONG)`, when casting pointer to an int one should use corresponding PTR types, such as `UINT_PTR`. Anyway there is no need to cast in this case at all.

Comment: The warning message explains it all.   Your compiler considers a `BYTE *` is larger than a `ULONG`, so the conversion `(ULONG)iterator` does truncation (i.e. drops some information).   The error is because you have employed your compiler with a setting that causes warnings to be treated as errors.     In fact, no `(ULONG)` conversions should be needed at all to get your code (at least, the partial code you have shown) to compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cast char pointer to long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841703/cast-char-pointer-to-long)

Comment: Surely you meant (ULONG)(iterator - params->dataStart) to truncate ptrdiff_t to ULONG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **LONG** type is 4 byte wide, while a pointer type such as **BYTE*** has the width of the architecture, *i.e. 32 bits or  4 byte on a x86 platform, and 64bits (8byte) on an x64 architecture*. Hence this would compile fine on a x86 platform, but gives warnings (that are treated as errors) on a 64 bit platform.

For the x64 architecture,  the correct conversion would be towards numerical type "**LONG LONG**" or **UINT64** and similar types, or if you really do not care you can *static_cast (x)* the value.

Comment: Use `ULONG_PTR` instead of `ULONG`